# Assuming the overall shape is still 10x10x10 cubes, can you subdivide cubes to create more floorspace with Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

With the simplest arrangement possible, Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion allows for 5000 sq ft. of space.

But suppose I was okay with slightly cramped quarters, would it be possible to arrange 25 cubes in a 5x5 rectangle, put another 25 cubes on top of those cubes, and then put walls at 6' 8'' (=20' / 3) in order to create 3 floors with 7500 sq ft of floor space?

Comment: I reckon that only gnomes have (gnome-height) truly magnificent mansions. Everyone else must **kneel** (or polymorph) inside their really magnificent mansions.

Answer (score 18):

## Yes.

The spell's description explicitly says:

> **You can create any floorplan you like,** but the space can't exceed 50 cubes, each cube being 10 feet on each side."

That sentence unambiguously says that you're allowed to place internal walls and doors in the space wherever you want, provided the mansion's total volume fits within 50 cubes.

Furthermore, the spell's description also says:

> The place is furnished and decorated as you choose.

So, even if your GM were to have a fit of madness and arbitrarily declare that the *mansion* can't have internal walls or that the internal walls have to run along the outsides of the cubes for some reason, you could simply declare that the mansion has an open plan, that its furnishings include a number of luxuriously-painted folding screens, and that your one hundred totally obedient <s>copies of Viggo Mortensen</s> servants can simply rearrange them to form new rooms on the fly.

**Real talk time:** The interior layout of the mansion is unlikely to be important in play. The mansion only lasts a day, and the number of creatures who can enter it is limited to the ones you designate when you cast the spell. This means that very few plot- or adventure-relevant encounters will occur within the mansion; it's mostly just a place for the party to take a load off and rest up in style - and in that case, the mansion's layout is purely a matter of flavour.

About the only time when a mansion's layout *might* be important to the game is if the caster deliberately use the spell to create an ideal ambush location or dungeon that they expect foes to enter - and if that happens, the ability to choose appropriate furnishings alone is already enough for them to make it a perfect ambush site or labyrinth for their needs, as heavy iron furniture already does all the things you'd want internal walls for anyway.

As such, there's really no reason for a GM to put more limitations on the layout of the mansion than are already on the spell.

Comment: Wait, the MM servants my players conjure have the likeness of Sir Sean Connery at his prime. I was unaware of variants of the spell that conjure other Hollywood stars. Interesting.

Answer (score -4):

I'm unsure how the above answer reached the conclusion "Yes" when it immediately quote the rule that says "No".

Each room **must** be at least 10 Ft wide. You simply cannot make one smaller, so 5 Ft is just not possible.

Comment: The spell says nothing about the *rooms*, just that the layout of the mansion as a whole must be made up of up to 50 10' cubes. "Cube" != "Room"